# Convert bash shell script call in arara rule from version 4 to version 6

Tags: rules, conversion, arara

I have the following rule in arara 4 that calls a bash shell and executes a command in this shell:

```
!config
identifier: OCbootstrap
name: OCbootstrap
commands:
- <arara> bash -i -c OCbootstrap @{build}
arguments: 
- identifier: build
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.build}
  default: "Build"
```

I'm having some trouble converting this to arara 6...  the version below gives me the following error:  "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present" but there is no line information so I don't really know where things go wrong...

```
!config
identifier: OCbootstrap
name: OCbootstrap
authors: 
- Marc De Graef
commands: 
- name: execOCbootstrap 
  command: > 
  @{
   return getCommand(shell, args, OCb, build)
  }
arguments: 
- identifier: shell
  flag: 'bash'
  default: 'bash'
- identifier: args
  flag: '-i -c'
  default: '-i -c'
- identifier: OCb
  flag: 'OCbootstrap'
  default: 'OCbootstrap'
- identifier: build
  flag: > 
  @{
    parameters.build
  }
  default: "Build"
```

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Thanks,
Marc.

Comment: Hi! Working on it. Thanks! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Marc,you were *so close* to getting a perfect rule! `:)` Congrats!

If it's okay, I will take the opportunity to comment your rule:

```yaml
!config
identifier: OCbootstrap
name: OCbootstrap
authors: 
- Marc De Graef
```

We are good to go so far! `:)`

```yaml
commands: 
- name: execOCbootstrap
```

Perfect, we have our first command in our list (which, incidentally, it's the only one).

```yaml
  command: > 
  @{
   return getCommand(shell, args, OCb, build)
  }
```

Sadly, this won't work, and the reason is that YAML requires an indentation level when using the folded style. We would need to add at least one space in the beginning of each line  that's relevant to `command`. Also, since `-c` requires a string containing the command to be executed, we might need to do an update.

```yaml
arguments: 
- identifier: shell
  flag: 'bash'
  default: 'bash'
```

This is definitely not wrong at all, but I personally think we could remove it and save one argument processing by replacing the variable by its value, as it's definitely constant (we do not have any expansions whatsoever happening here).

```yaml
- identifier: args
  flag: '-i -c'
  default: '-i -c'
```

The same comment above applies here, but I would add that `'-i -c'` *might* cause unexpected behaviours from your script. The reason is that, in fact, we have two flags — `-i` and `-c` — instead of just one — which `-i -c` denotes. A fix for this would be replacing `'-i -c'` by `[ '-i', '-c' ]`, which is a list of two strings (in this case, two flags).

```yaml
- identifier: OCb
  flag: 'OCbootstrap'
  default: 'OCbootstrap'
```

I would use a constant value instead of an argument. Same reasoning as the other entries. `:)`

```yaml
- identifier: build
  flag: > 
  @{
    parameters.build
  }
  default: "Build"
```

It's all good except for the indentation issue when using the folded style. Just add at least one space in the beginning of each line that's relevant to `flag`.

That's it. `:)` Here's my humble proposal:

```yaml
!config
identifier: OCbootstrap
name: OCbootstrap
authors: 
- Marc De Graef
commands:
```

Nothing new here. `:)`

```yaml
- name: Executing OCbootstrap 
  command: > 
    @{
        call = 'OCbootstrap ' + build[0];
        return getCommand('bash', '-i', '-c', call);
    }
```

I did four things here:

1. I renamed the command `name` just for aesthetic purposes. `:)`
2. I added an indentation level for the folded style.
3. I replaced most of the arguments by their values — referential transparency at its finest. `:)`
4. Since `-c` from `bash` requires the command to execute (namely, `OCbootstrap`) and its potential arguments (namely, the value hold by `build`) as a quoted string, this means for us that we have a single argument, so I created a new local variable named `call` and assigned to it the command `OCbootstrap` + a space (string build, hence the need of it) + the first value of `build` (it's worth mentioning that we normalise values as a list of strings, so `build` is technically `[ 'Build' ]` and not `'Build'` as one would think) and then we pass it to the `getCommand(...)` method as a single argument. When executed, we will get this:

   ```
   [DR] (OCbootstrap) Executing OCbootstrap
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
   Author: Marc De Graef
   About to run: [bash, -i, -c, OCbootstrap Build] @ /home/paulo
   ```

See how `OCbootstrap Build` is now an argument on its own. `:)`

```yaml
arguments: 
- identifier: build
  flag: > 
    @{
        parameters.build
    }
  default: "Build"
```

Then we are left with just one argument, which I simply added an indentation level to each line relevant to `flag`.

The new rule:

```yaml
!config
identifier: OCbootstrap
name: OCbootstrap
authors: 
- Marc De Graef
commands: 
- name: Executing OCbootstrap 
  command: > 
    @{
        call = 'OCbootstrap ' + build[0];
        return getCommand('bash', '-i', '-c', call);
    }
arguments: 
- identifier: build
  flag: > 
    @{
        parameters.build
    }
  default: "Build"
```

Hope that helps! `:)`

Comment: Thanks Paulo!  very detailed and useful response.  It appears that the resulting command is "bash -i -c OCbootstrap Build-a" and unfortunately the bash shell then fails since it expects to see the following command "bash -i -c 'OCbootstrap Build-a'" ... Is there a simple way to add the single quotes in the getCommand line?

Comment: @MarcDeGraef Will draft something, just a minute. `:)`

Comment: @MarcDeGraef Hi Marc! I updated the rule and added an explanation. Could you check if it works? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Paulo!  That works like a charm.  I appreciate your time!

Comment: @MarcDeGraef great to hear, Marc! I actually forgot about the `bash` thing about string-based commands. Oopsie. `:)` Thanks for the pointer! Now the universe is in balance once again!